# Python - os.getcwd() doesn't return the full path

Tags: python, directory, getcwd

At the start of the file, I specified the path using:

```
path = r"C:\Documents\Data"
os.chdir(path)
```

Later on, I want to iterate through subfolders in the `Data` folder. This folder contains `2018`, which contains `Level2A`. I do this with:

```
for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in subdirectories:
            if filename.endswith('.SAFE'):
                print(filename)
                print(os.getcwd())
```

When printing the subfolder's name, it works; it prints `folder_name.SAFE`. When I, however want to print the path which it's currently looking at, I get the following:

```
print(os.getcwd())
>>> C:\Documents\Data
```

Why do I not get `C:\Documents\Data\2018\Level2A` whose file I printed is? What do I have to change to do get this?

Comment: Because "the path it's currently looking at" has **nothing to do with** the current working directory, and there's **no reason** why it should be expected to. The traversal doesn't work by changing the process CWD; it works by asking the system what's in those folders.

Answer (score 2):

[`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) returns the current working directory and that is the directory you changed into using `os.chdir()`

To get the folder of the file, we can look at the docs of [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames)

and

> To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

So in your case, try:

```py
print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Also, check out the newer [`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module

Comment: Thanks! Now it works as intended!

Answer (score 1):

everytime you exceute os.getcwd(), you will get your current directory.
if you need full path of filename that contain ".SAFE" on it's filename, you need to print something like this :

```
for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in subdirectories:
        if filename.endswith('.SAFE'):
            print(filename)
            print(root+"/"+filename)
```